# Is there a way to trigger the clickability of a button in tkinter?

Tags: python, user-interface, events, tkinter

I'd like to have a button, which is only performing a command after some criterion is fulfilled.

This is our button :

```
import tkinter as tk
from matplotlib import *
from tkinter import ttk, messagebox, filedialog

class Hauptmenu(tk.Frame): 

    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent) 

        ttk.Button(self, text='Button', command=self.doSomething).grid(row=7,column=4, sticky="w")
        clickability_criterion=False
```

So I want the button to be functional after I set the criterion to True.

Is there any elegant way to achieve this?

Comment: You mean you want to enable that button only after a certain condition is met?

Comment: This is exactly what I want.

Answer (score 4):

There's a `state` field when you define a button, that you can set to either `ENABLED` or `DISABLED`. You can define your button do be `DISABLED` at startup, like that:

```
import tkinter as tk
from matplotlib import *
from tkinter import ttk, messagebox, filedialog

tk = tk.Tk()

myButton = ttk.Button(tk, text='Button', command=self.doSomething, state = 'disabled')
myButton.grid(row=7,column=4, sticky="w")
```

When some condition is met you can change the status to `NORMAL`:

```
myButton['state'] = 'normal'
```

This should do the trick.

EDIT: as for the runtime update I'd define a method in your class updating the status for you, something like that:

```
class Hauptmenu:
    def __init__(self, parent):
        self.myParent = parent  
        self.myContainer = tk.Frame(parent)
        self.myContainer.pack()
        self.button = tk.Button(self.myContainer)
        self.button.configure(text="Button", command=self.doSomething, state = 'disabled')
        self.button.pack()

    def doSomething(self):
        print('This button has been pressed')

    def changeButtonState(self, state):
        self.button['state'] = state



root = tk.Tk()
c = Hauptmenu(root)
c.changeButtonState('normal')
tk.mainloop()
```

Comment: the button is still clickable and functional for me ... ?

Comment: Sorry, I think `DISABLED` should not be a string, I'll update the answer.

Comment: yeah I tried this aswell, cause I've seen it somewhere, but this causes the program to crash at start...

Comment: That's weird, I've tried this very simple example on my computer and it works. Maybe the error is somewhere else?

Comment: You should add also the correct import, otherwise `DISABLED` and ~NORMAL` variable are not defined.

Comment: I'm using ttk-elements all the time. The thing is: With a simple tk.Button it is working.

Comment: It's simply state='disabled'/'normal'  ... works as intended! =)

Comment: Is it possible to change the state of the button during runtime?

Comment: OK, using your imports then yes, you should use the string `'disabled'/'normal'`. As for the runtime change: I'd define a method in your class doing that, but that depends a bit on how you're using your application.

Answer (score 2):

you can create a disabled button like so:

```
ttk.Button(self, text='Button', state = ttk.DISABLED, command=self.doSomething).grid(row=7,column=4, sticky="w")
```

and then enable it like so:

```
variable_inwhich_button_is_saved.configure(state=ttk.ENABLED)
```

Comment: with state=ttk.DISABLED everything is crashing, so I used  state='DISABLED'. But the button is still clickable and functional..?!

Comment: I get an AttributeError: module 'tkinter.ttk' has no attribute 'DISABLED'

Comment: could you update the question with the imports you are using (or the whole code if you can)?

Comment: The whole code is too long, but I added the imports and the particular page the button belongs to.

Comment: your problem is that DISABLED and ENABLED are defined in tkinter itself.

Comment: I got it... It's simply state='disabled'/'normal' ... Thanks for your patience!

Comment: Depends: Is it possible to change the state of the button during runtime?

Comment: @Tybald It can be done only at runtime. The button doesn't even exists if the program is not running.